# How to call different actionListeners?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

My program has one button, and the other one is a JTextField. The action listener for the button and the textfield are different. I'm using:

> `textfield.addActionListener(this);
>
>      button.addActionListener(this);`

... inside my constructor.

They both do the same actionListener. How can I call their respective methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implementing `ActionListener` in the class of both components. So, when an action happens, `actionPerformed` method of the class is called for both of them. You can do following to separate them:

1-Create a separate class and implement `ActionListener` interface in it and add it as a actionListener for one of the components.

2-In `actionPerformed` method, there is a parameter with `ActionEvent` type. Call *getSource* method of it and check if it returns the object of `JTextField` or `JButton` by putting an if statement and do separate things accordingly.

Comment: Thank you :) that's what I had in mind as well after skimming through the comments~

Comment: I think it is horrible practice for this situation only.. You may find it very useful and best practice for many use cases. Think you have hundreds of panels and in each of them a certain button just opens up the text written in the textfield in a new dialog. In that separate class, you may store the associated textfield and open up the dialog. So, if you have one specific job for many components in a system with hundred of panels, you have to use the first option...

Answer (score 3):

Obviously both components share an `ActionListener`. If you want to determine which component generated the `ActionEvent`, invoke [`getSource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29). And from there, you can typecast (if needed), and then invoke that particular component's methods.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: Uh the link doesn't work. However, I think I may know what you're saying. I'll try to fix my code with an if-else statement inside :) Thanks~

Comment: @alicedimarco, The link is fixed; sorry!

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way to do what is asked is the following:

```
textfield.addActionListener(this);
button.addActionListener(this);
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if( e.getSource().getClass().equals(JTextField.class) ){
        System.out.println("textfield");
        //Código para el textfield
    }
    if( e.getSource().getClass().equals(JButton.class) ){
        System.out.println("JButton");
        //Código para el JButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the English language only please.
Utilizar el idioma Inglés solamente por favor

Answer (score 0):

When an action listener is activated, because someone click your button, the method `actionPerformed` is called. As you havae set `this` as an action listener, you should have a method `actionPerformed` in your class. This is the method called in both cases.

Something like:

```
class MyClass implements ActionListener {

  public MyClass() {
    ...
    textfield.addActionListener(this) ;
    button.addActionListener(this) ;
    ...
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // This is the method being called when:
    // - the button is clicked and
    // - the textfield activated
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though if you have not given your sample code, but I can understand what is there.

Here is an example of how to add listener to any `JComponent`. (Dont try to run this code!!!)

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class EventListeners extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    TextArea txtArea;
    String Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide;
    int i = 10, j = 20, sum = 0, Sub = 0, Mul = 0, Div = 0;

    public void init() {
        txtArea = new TextArea(10, 20);
        txtArea.setEditable(false);
        add(txtArea, "center");
        Button b = new Button("Add");
        Button c = new Button("Subtract");
        Button d = new Button("Multiply");
        Button e = new Button("Divide");

        // YOU ARE DOING SOMETHING LIKE THIS
        // THIS WILL WORK, BUT CAN BE A BAD EXMPLE
        b.addActionListener(this);
        c.addActionListener(this);
        d.addActionListener(this);
        e.addActionListener(this);

        add(b);
        add(c);
        add(d);
        add(e);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sum = i + j;
        txtArea.setText("");
        txtArea.append("i = " + i + "\t" + "j = " + j + "\n");
        Button source = (Button) e.getSource();

        // you can work with them like shown below
                    Button source = (Button) e.getSource();
        if (source.getLabel() == "Add") {
            txtArea.append("Sum : " + sum + "\n");
        }
        if (source.getLabel() == "Subtract") {
            txtArea.append("Sub : " + Sub + "\n");
        }
        if (source.getLabel() == "Multiply") {
            txtArea.append("Mul = " + Mul + "\n");
        }
        if (source.getLabel() == "Divide") {
            txtArea.append("Divide = " + Div);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You should do something like below

```
        Button b = new Button("Add");
        Button c = new Button("Subtract");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // implement what is expected for b button 
            }
        });
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // implement what is expected for c button 
            }
        });
        // and so on...
        // but yes we can improve it
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set different ActionCommands on each component.
In the actionPerformed method you can check the ActionCommand of the event:

```
private static final String TEXT_CMD = "text";  // or something more meaningful
private static final String BUTTON_CMD = "button";

...

    textfield.setActionCommand(TEXT_CMD);
    textfield.addActionListener(this);

    button.setActionCommand(BUTTON_CMD);
    button.addActionListener(this);

...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getActionCommand()) {
        case TEXT_CMD:
            // do textfield stuff here
            break;
        case BUTTON_CMD:
            // do button stuff here
            break;
        default:
            // error message?
            break;
    }
}
```